# Confused by "#pragma GCC diagnostic push/pop"

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma

I'm trying to use "#pragma GCC diagnostic push" and "#pragma GCC diagnostic pop" to turn warnings on for my code and then back off (for example, once the header ends). But the warnings are not getting turned off as expected when I pop. As a simple example of this:

```
int main(int, char*[]) {
  int i;
  unsigned int ui;
  i==ui;  // no warning as expected
// this push doesn't make any difference
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wsign-compare"
  i==ui;  // warns as expected

// this push doesn't make any difference in warning output
#pragma GCC diagnostic push

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-compare"
  i==ui; // no warning as expected

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
  i==ui; // warns as expected

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
  i==ui; // warns unexpectedly

// I can put as many pops as I want here, nothing changes
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
  i==ui; // warns unexpected
  return 0;
}
```

With gcc 4.6 (and 4.7) and no warnings enabled from the command line (or even -Wno-sign-compare passed on the command line) the warnings are as marked in the text. That is, one doesn't seem to be able to pop things away back to the command line values. Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?

Any pointers on how to get things to work?

I see the same behavior with the example from the gcc manual:

```
int test() {
  int a,b,c,d;
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wuninitialized"
  foo(a);                  /* warning is given for this one */
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wuninitialized"
  foo(b);                  /* no diagnostic for this one */
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
  foo(c);                  /* warning is given for this one */
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
  foo(d);                  /* warning is given here too, for some reason */
}
```

Comment: I think the first push only pushes the state of the command line options. Here, because there aren't any, there's nothing to push. That's the only solution I can come up with anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in descriding how gcc *should* behave. I also had a similar issue with gcc version 4.8.5, but same code compiled as expected in gcc version 11.3.1. So I guess there was a bug that was fixed along the way, but I could not find an issue for it amongst gcc bugs.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35530317)

Comment: I updated the wording of my answer, I do answer the question, please explain how I do not answer it.

Comment: In your previous wording it sounded more like an "I have the same problem" post. Now it's clear that you know GCC is wrong in this case. If you have informations about which versions work and which don't please include that information. Also, if there's a workaround for the buggy version, that would be helpful as well.